# How to setup the proxy info in yypkg for sherpa.exe when installing Win-builds Project

Tags: batch-file, gcc

I am trying to install the latest GCC compiler on windows 7 by using "Win-builds Project". Since the company I am working for has proxy. When I run the command win-install.bat. I got an error:

```
http://win-builds.org/1.3.0/packages/windows_64/package_list.el:
2014-02-21 11:39:44 ERROR 407: Proxy Authentication Required.
```

In the batch file, I found code:

```
yypkg -init
yypkg -config -setpreds host=%_YY_ARCH%-w64-mingw32
yypkg -config -setpreds target=%_YY_ARCH%-w64-mingw32
sherpa -set-mirror http://win-builds.org/1.3.0/packages/windows_%_YY_BITS%
```

I think the yypkg.exe does the initialization work and configs sherpa and let sherpa.exe to download and install files.

My question is how can config yypkg my username and password? I did google search, but I cannot find any info about yypkg nor how to config sherpa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[enter code here][1]`Proxy set up can be done via command line
[How can I set a proxy server for gem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059670/how-to-set-proxy-for-command-prompt)

```
  set http_proxy=http://your_proxy:your_port
  set http_proxy=http://username:password@your_proxy:your_port
  set https_proxy=https://your_proxy:your_port
  set https_proxy=https://username:password@your_proxy:your_port
```

These command snippets need to be entered on 'cmd.exe', and before running the wget, to download files manually via portable wget as described on page:
http://win-builds.org/doku.php/download_and_installation_from_windows

few IMPORTANT Pointers, after the packages have been downloaded manually, and running the 'yypkg-1.5.0.exe'

1. At first the Application UI is unresponsive, DO NOT CLOSE IT
   After some time, change mirror dialog appears where you would need to type/paste the Local folders location(this is the folder where files were downloaded manually)
2. Local folder path needs to be similar to the following where 'package_list.el.tar.xz' file resides.
   file:///C:/usr/MinGW/1.5.0/packages/windows_64

after that all works fine