# How can I set a proxy server for gem?

Tags: windows, proxy, rubygems

I am unable to install SASS through command prompt.

I tried below steps

```
c:\gem install sass
```

I am getting below error:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'sass' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Errno::ECONNREFUSED: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2) (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

Please help me,

Answer (score 147):

For http/https proxy with or without authentication:

Run one of the following commands in cmd.exe

```
set http_proxy=http://your_proxy:your_port
set http_proxy=http://username:password@your_proxy:your_port
set https_proxy=https://your_proxy:your_port
set https_proxy=https://username:password@your_proxy:your_port
```

Comment: How do I then remove these settings?

Comment: @minseong  You don't need to remove them as these settings are only active within a command prompt window. If you close your command prompt window and reopen it you'll find out that you need to reenter the commands for it to work.

Comment: If want to clear the settings and don't want to close command prompt, use the following commands "set http_proxy=" and "set https_proxy="

Comment: how to escape if password has a @ character

Comment: @gaurav5430: try `%40`

Comment: is there any way to use the windows login for this?

Comment: I don't know how this answer got those upvotes but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: ok and how do I display the currently set proxy? echo %HTTP_PROXY% does nothing

Comment: Also you can see actual environment proxy vars with: set http_proxy . If isn't setted it'll appear "Environment var http_proxy not defined.

Comment: If also fetching from an internal location It's sometimes necessary to also set `no_proxy` to bypass the proxy for those subdomains / IP addresses.   Note that parsing/behaviour around the `no_proxy` list is application-dependent and frequently inconsistent.

Answer (score 19):

You need to write this in the command prompt:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://your_proxy:your_port
```

Answer (score 12):

You need to add `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables as described [here](http://kaamka.blogspot.ca/2009/06/httpproxy-environment-variable.html).

Comment: Thanks, @TylerH. I checked on my personal laptop, and there was probably something about the fancy formatting that couldn't render in our enterprise

Answer (score 3):

When setting http_proxy and https_proxy, you are also probably going to need no_proxy for URLs on the same side of the proxy. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272656(v=vs.120).aspx

Answer (score 3):

In Addition to @Yifei answer. If you have **special character** like @, &, $

You have to go with [percent-encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) | [encode](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) the special characters. E.g. instead of this:

```
http://foo:B@r@http-gateway.domain.org:80
```

you write this:

```
http://foo:B%40r@http-gateway.domain.org:80
```

So `@` gets replaced with `%40`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `export http_proxy=http://your_proxy:your_port`

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers here actually helped my case (proxy + password), instead I found a solution on a Github issue:

https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1068

Basically I had to set three variables:

```
set http_proxy=proxy_ip:port
set http_proxy_user=user
set http_proxy_pass=password
```