# Proxy Settings for Windows 7 Command Prompt

Tags: windows, curl, proxy, cmd

I am trying to use cURL in the Command Prompt, but I dont understand where I have problems. I have been told that I need to configure a proxy tothe Command Prompt so that it can access the sites I am calling on.
This is what I want to run: `curl -glob "api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?&search=receivedate:[20040101+TO+20150101]&limit=1"`
I have cURL installed, but always face errors because it is not connecting. Is there a simple way to set up a proxy for/through the Command Prompt in Windows 7?

*I also do not have admin rights, so I cannot change the system settings.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to set proxy for command prompt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059670/how-to-set-proxy-for-command-prompt)

Comment: @KenWhite I had seen that before. I do not have admin rights, so I cannot change the system settings. Is there another way to add a proxy?

Comment: Type the SET commands from the command prompt before typing your curl command, as in `SET http_proxy=<your proxy>` and `SET https_proxy=<your proxy>` (or better yet use a batch file to set them and then run curl).

Answer (score 3):

You can set your proxy using a `set` command in windows:

```
set http_proxy=http://<yourproxyaddress>:<port>
```

Then you can connect your curl requests to external sites.

Comment: The URL should inside ""

Answer (score 2):

Some proxies require specific authentication headers to be set, so be aware of those as well. In my case, it's `--proxy-ntlm` in the example below:

```
curl -x webproxy.net:8080 -U usernaname:password http://google.com --proxy-ntlm
```

But there're other options:

`--proxy-digest` and `--proxy-negotiate`

Lastly, cURL has a super friendly doc page, so be sure to check it out.