# How to set proxy exception in Windows in the command line?

Tags: windows, proxy, command, prompt

I've used the information available in this thread [How can I set a proxy server for gem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059670/how-to-set-proxy-for-command-prompt) to set my http/https proxy settings. And they generally work fine, but they're causing me trouble in some situations, so I would like to be able to define exceptions to what's defined with `%HTTP_PROXY%` / `%HTTPS_PROXY%`.

Is there a way to do that in Windows?

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc731131(WS.10).aspx), proxy at all, and exceptions for proxy could be defined in command like

```
set proxy proxy-server="http=myproxy;https=sproxy:88" bypass-list="*.contoso.com"
```

where "*.contoso.com" is what you want to put in exceptions list. Just make sure that you running this command under netsh winhttp context.