# Using system Proxy in RestClient

Tags: ruby, proxy, rubygems, rest-client

I use RestClient to get pages over internet. Also this script I made is proxy enabled by using `RestClient.proxy = "http://proxy.example.com/"`. 
But I dont always use proxy. So instead of manually setting proxy on and off inside the script I wanted the script to read system settings automatically.

The GitHub documentation states:

> Often the proxy URL is set in an environment variable, so you can do this to use whatever proxy the system is configured to use:
>
> `RestClient.proxy = ENV['http_proxy']`

I dont see how can this detect if system proxy in on or not here. It although can detect what proxy address I am using *i suppose*.

- Also how specifically can I use this?
- Also how do I specify the proxy port?
- AND how can I get the system's proxy settings and then
  follow up with `RestClient.proxy = "http://proxy.example.com/"`
  **IF** proxy is enabled.

Comment: I am a Windows user.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing magical about it.

`http_proxy` is assumed set by a user or administrator, and can be of the form `http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy.example.org:8080` with both the credentials and port optional.

None of these magically import from the system; *nix systems generally don't have a "system proxy setting" and I don't think you can get at Windows' proxy settings determined in the network settings.

Comment: Okay I get the *actual way* by which i can use the port in the address but I can definitely set windows proxy by `system("REG ADD \"HKCU\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings\" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f")` So is it not possible to read this registry as well some how?

Answer (score 0):

restClient.Proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy(yourProxyServer, yourProxyPort);

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059670/how-can-i-set-a-proxy-server-for-gem/28153935#28153935) answer tells how to add proxy via cmd. Maybe this could be of some use. You can run these commands using `system()`. You may not need to specifically specify proxy in RestClient. **!UNTESTED!** This also has an option for port. The windows proxy and terminal proxies are different.

So your 2nd and 3rd questions are answered hopefully.

Comment: Thanks but this is not my question. This way I still have to manually enter the proxy if i am using one.